# Transition probability of Brownian Bridge

Tags: probability

This is homework so no answers please

Consider Gaussian $X_i\sim N(0,t_{i}(1-t_{i}))$ s.t. $\frac{X_{1}}{(1-t_{1})}$ and $\frac{X_{2}}{(1-t_{2})}-\frac{X_{1}}{(1-t_{1})}$ are independent (with distribution $N(0,\frac{t_{1}}{1-t_{1}})$ and $N(0,\frac{t_{2}-t_{1}}{(1-t_{1})(1-t_{2})})$).

The problem is to show $P(X_{1}\in dx_{1},X_{2}\in dx_{2})=\frac{p(1-t_{2},-x_{2})}{p(1,0)}p(t_{1},x_{1}),p(t_{2}-t_{1},x_{2}-x_{1})dx_{1}dx_{2}$, where p is the Gaussian Kernel.

Attempt; any mistakes:

We have $P(X_{1}=x_{1},X_{2}=x_{2})=P(\frac{X_{1}}{(1-t_{1})}=\frac{x_{1}}{(1-t_{1})},\frac{X_{2}}{(1-t_{2})}-\frac{X_{1}}{(1-t_{1})}=\frac{x_{2}}{(1-t_{2})}-\frac{x_{1}}{(1-t_{1})})$.

Thus, the transformed joint density will be

$$p(\frac{x_{1}}{1-t_{1}},\frac{t_{1}}{1-t_{1}} )p(\frac{x_{2}}{(1-t_{2})}-\frac{x_{1}}{(1-t_{1})},\frac{t_{2}-t_{1}}{(1-t_{1})(1-t_{2})} )\frac{1}{(1-t_{1})(1-t_{2})}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{(2\pi t_{1})^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{1}{(2\pi (t_{2}-t_{1}))^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{1}{(2\pi (1-t_{2}))^{\frac{1}{2} }} (2\pi)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot $$

$$exp[-\frac{x^{2}_{1}}{2t_{1}(1-t_{1})}-\frac{(\frac{x_{2}}{(1-t_{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}}(1-t_{1})^{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{x_{1}}{(1-t_{1})^{\frac{1}{2}}}(1-t_{2})^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2}}{2(t_{2}-t_{1})}]$$

The remaining problem is the exponential term.

We want it to be

$$[-\frac{x^{2}_{1}}{2t_{1}}-\frac{(x_{2}-x_{1})^{2}}{2(t_{2}-t_{1})}-\frac{(1-x_{2})^{2}}{2(1-t_{2})}]$$

But after arduous calculation, I get a contradition if those two terms are equal. So I think I made a mistake somewhere above.

Thanks